# Optimize nested loops for pattern-filling an array, to help the compiler produce efficient ARM assembly?

Tags: c, assembly, arm, micro-optimization

I have just been given an assignment to re-write the following C function, to help the ARM compiler produce more efficient assembly code. Does anyone know how to do this?

```
void some_function(int *data)
{
    int  i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < 64; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 64; j++)
            data[j + 64*i] = (i + j)/2;
    }
}
```

Comment: The compiler can probably do a good job already.  One possibility is to introduce `int k = 0;` outside the loops, and use `data[k++] = (i + j) / 2;` in the inner loop.

Comment: I agree with Jonathan on trusting the compiler. And I also want to propose an optimisation. Try to get rid of the `/2` inside the inner loop. For that change the loop to `for (j = 0; j < 64; j+=2)` and do two (instead of one) appropriate assignments inside. This is similar to (though not exactly) loop-unrolling and avoids a potentially expensive division.

Comment: The first step is to see if compilers make decent asm in the first place.  https://godbolt.org/z/q2BouY shows that GCC doesn't unroll the loop by default at `-O3`, although with `-O3 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mcpu=cortex-a53 -mfpu=neon` it auto-vectorizes.  Still several vector instructions per store which is not great.  @Yunnosch's suggestion to unroll the loop by 2 was my first thought, as well.  Even with `-funroll-loops` the add / asr don't optimize away :/  Silly compiler.  Maybe try unsigned to help the compiler.  I didn't try clang.

Comment: Otherwise let me repeat the old wisdom: optimisation should be based on measuring. Because any explicit optimisation attempt might in subtle ways foil otherwise possible optimsiations as done by the compiler and that depending on the environment. If you cannot measure then I assume that you got the assignment from a teacher (in contrast to superior) and demonstrating creativeness is probably the goal. In that case wait for what others think about proposals made here and select a few.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I consider making an answer here. Would you mind if I incorporate your comment-proposed optimisation, I'd give credit of course.

Comment: @Yunnosch — help yourself.  I'm not planning to answer (as opposed to commenting).  The 'divide by two' should be optimized to a shift, but there's likely room for improvement as you suggest.

Comment: @Yunnosch: unrolling by 2 appears to compile well, but defeats auto-vectorization.  https://godbolt.org/z/6_2RDK (IDK if that's a good or bad thing; with loads of constants inside the loop I think auto-vec was maybe hurting itself instead of doing vector increments.)  armv7-a clang aggressively fully unrolls/peels the inner loop, which again seems a bit much.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for your input and the obvious testing you did. I believe it means that environment specific measuring is very important. Some environment might suffer more/toomuch from the problem you mentioned, other so little that it has a net profit.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Most compilers don't need help with `/2` - it seems they can prove the value is always signed positive so they can use a simple right shift.  (Instead of implementing the differences in rounding semantics for negative dividends that would require multiple instructions to fix up the result of an `asr`.)  And you could always make the counters unsigned to make it easy for compilers.

Comment: @PeterCordes — yes. I meant "the compiler should optimize the divide by 2 to a shift", but I wasn't quite that explicit in my comment.

Comment: Both `i` and `j` cannot be greater than 64, so it is better defining them as `unsigned char`. Micros usually have dedicated 8/16 bit registers that speed up the execution. Also, if the micro has a 16 bit architecture the speed will dramatically increase. (@Yunnosch feel free to use it in your answer)

Comment: @RobertoCaboni: ARM is a 32-bit ISA; all 15 GP-integer registers are 32-bit (and so is the program counter = r15) and thus any sane ARM ABI picks `int` = `int32_t`.  Messing around with `unsigned char` only introduces the possibility of getting the compiler to waste instructions on `ubfx` or `and reg, reg, 0xff` to promote to `int`.

Comment: @PeterCorder you write "ARM" like there was an single model... :) I don't know the instruction set of every micro in the world, but I can say that embedded compulers optimizations are not so performing.

Comment: @PeterCordes I think you could make an upvoteable answer from your thoughts on how optimisation attempts might actually fail (vectorisation, etc.). It would be an interesting one, probably theoretical and without code. I'd love another example of code-free great answers. The same goes for everybody else.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni I am with you on possible optimisation via variable width. There are very small environment out there. I would consider a discussion on hardware-specific (in combination with corresponding compilers) optimisation potential worth an answer. It does not match the slightly more software-oriented direction of my answer. So I am not going to use your generours offer and instead look forward to an answer by you.

Comment: What a pointless assignment. It's generating a 64x64 matrix with FIXED VALUES. In other words, you can pre-generate the matrix, then simply `memcpy` it.

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE My thought exactly)) And the standard memcpy() is usually well optimized for the target CPU.

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE: Now you have added another 16,384 bytes of memory and of cache use to a program that did not need it, and for code that might run faster than `memcpy` anyway (the code as is only has to write memory, and the few operations in it might be done in parallel with that, whereas `memcpy` must both read and write).

Comment: @EricPostpischil That's why I call this assignment pointless. Any smart person won't perform this kind of table generation multiple times in runtime. Either you run it once during initialization, or you accept the 16kb in binary size.

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE: You perform a table generation multiple times during program execution if you need the table reset multiple times after multiple uses. Or, even if it is only needed once, initializing it at run-time may be faster than reading it from disk (from the program file’s data). Furthermore, student exercises do not need to be useful in production code in order to teach a student useful skills, any more than a specific weight lifting motion needs to be useful in real-life in order to build muscle and improve health.

Comment: @EricPostpischil This "micro-argument" is pretty much pointless unless we know *exactly* what is the goal of this exercise (from the professor's point of view). I definitely wouldn't advocate for using a pre-generated array "no matter what" but a student who would spot this possibility and at least mentioned it as a comment to this assignment would improve their chances for a higher mark (if I were the professor, that is).

Comment: @tum_: A purpose of many of my comments is not to settle a particular issue but to weed out trite and false “knowledge” before it is planted in too many students’ minds, takes root, grows, and spreads. In this case, the notion that one ought to adopt `memcpy` (because it is simple, easy, or already highly optimized) without truly evaluating the costs and benefits of it relative to other solutions is one such. There are many more novices than experts, and Stack Overflow serves as fertile ground for such weeds, and they are much harder to contain after they have spread.

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE: disagree on `memcpy`.  It should be possible to generate the right pattern in registers using loops at least as fast as `memcpy` could load them from mem, and 16kiB is enough that we'd expect it not to stay hot in L1d cache.  (Plus extra evictions cause cache misses for other code).  It's not a trivial pattern like `memset`, but still easy enough to gen on the fly.  `memcpy` *could* be better for a few use-cases, since it's easy and compilers don't seem to do great auto-vectorizing this.  (So max perf would need hand-vectorizing with NEON).

Answer (score 4):

First (as Jonathan Leffler mentioned) the compiler is likely to do so good a job already that trying to optimise by writing specific C code is usually commercially questionable, i.e. you lose more money via development time than you can make by slightly faster code.
But sometimes it is worth it; let's assume it is the case here.

If you do optimise, do so while measuring. It is very possible to write code which ends up being less optimal, because in subtle ways otherwise possible compiler optimisations are foiled. Also, whether and how much optimisation works depends on the environment, i.e. measuring in all potential environments is necessary.

Ok, after that wise-cracking, here is code in which I demonstrate optimisations as proposed in comments, one of them by Jonathan Leffler:

```
/* Jonathan Leffler */
void some_function(int *data)
{
    int  i, j;
    int  k = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 64; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 64; j++)
        {
            data[k++] = (i + j)/2;
        }
    }
}

/* Yunnosch 1, loop unrolling by 2 */
void some_function(int *data)
{
    int  i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < 64; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 64; j+=2)
            data[j +     64*i] = (i + j  )/2;
            data[j + 1 + 64*i] = (i + j+1)/2;
    }
}

/* Yunnosch 1 and Jonathan Leffler */
void some_function(int *data)
{
    int  i, j;
    int k=0; /* Jonathan Leffler */

    for (i = 0; i < 64; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 64; j+=2) /* Yunnosch */
        {
            data[k++] = (i + j  )/2;
            data[k++] = (i + j+1)/2; /* Yunnosch */
        }
    }
}

/* Yunnosch 2, avoiding the /2, including Jonathan Leffler */
/* Well, duh. This is harder than I thought... 
   I admit that this is NOT tested, I want to demonstrate the idea.
   Everybody feel free to help the very grateful me with fixing errors. */
void some_function(int *data)
{
    int  i, j;
    int  k=0;

    for (i = 0; i < 32; i++) /* magic numbers I normally avoid, 32 is 64/2 */
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 32; j++)
        {
            data[k     ] = (i + j);
            data[k+1   ] = (i + j);
            data[k  +64] = (i + j);
            data[k+1+64] = (i + j +1);
            k+=2;
        }
        k+=64;
    }
}
```

The last version is based on the following observable 2x2 group pattern in the desired result, as seen in a 2D interpretation:

```
00 11 ...
01 12 ...

11 22 ...
12 23 ...
.. ..
.. ..
.. ..
´´´´
```

Comment: Oh hmm, yeah avoiding `/2` is not as easy as I thought in my comments under the question.  Untested version: https://godbolt.org/z/vVzwsY that unrolls the *outer* loop by 2 as well, with 2 versions of the inner loop to cover the fact that `1+0` and `0+1` don't "overcome" the right shift, but `1+1` does so we have `store; tmp++; store`  in the loop that handles odd `i`.  Fusing those loops into one that stores to `j+0..1 + 64*(i+0)` and `j+0..1 + 64*(i+1)` might be good, reusing the same tmp, if ARM microarchitectures aren't bothered by two output streams to different cache lines.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for your input. I hope the timing makes it plausible if I state that my proposal was done before knowing yours.

Comment: That last version looks right to me.  It's the same basic idea / analysis of the 2x2 pattern as my unrolled version, but yours keeps it fused into one loop.  https://godbolt.org/z/TSHQj6 shows it compiles sensibly, with right-looking offsets in addressing modes.  At first I was suspicious but then I spotted the `k+=64` that advances past the `k+64` part we stored. (And most of the instructions in the inner loop are stores, so on a simple core that bottlenecks on instruction throughput, this has a high fraction of useful work.  And the outer loop logic is very simple, good for code size)

Comment: Nice edit. I was just done reviewing (finding most issues myself), when magically they all fixed themselves. @JonathanLeffler

Answer (score 4):

Optimizing C code to generate "more efficient assembly code" for a specific compiler/processor is something you normally shouldn't do. Write clear and easy to understand C code and let the compiler do the optimization.

Even if you make all kinds of tricks with the C code and end up with "more efficient assembly code" for your specific compiler/processor, it may turn out that a simple compiler upgrade may ruin the whole thing and you'll have to change the C code again.

For something as simple as your code, write it in assembler code from the start. But be aware that you'll have to be a real expert in that processor/assembly language to beat a decent compiler.

Anyway... If we want to guess, this is my guess:

```
void some_function(int *data)
{
    int  i, j, x;

    for (i = 0; i < 64; i++)
    {
        // Handle even i-values
        x = i/2;
        for (j = 0; j < 64; j += 2)
        {
            *data = x;
            ++data;
            *data = x;
            ++data;
            ++x;        // Increment after writing to data twice
        }

        ++i;

        // Handle odd i-values
        x = i/2;
        for (j = 0; j < 64; j += 2)
        {
            *data = x;
            ++data;
            ++x;        // Increment after writing to data once
            *data = x;
            ++data;
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is 1) to replace the array-indexing with pointer increments and 2) to replace the `(i+j)/2` with integer increments.

I have **not** done any measurement so I can't say for sure that this will be a good solution. I'll leave that to OP.

---

Same idea as above, but with a few more tweaks (proposed by @user3386109)

```
void some_function(int *data)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    {
        // when i is even, the output is in matched pairs
        int value = i;
        for (int j = 0; j < 32; j++)
        {
            *data++ = value;
            *data++ = value++;
        }

        // when i is odd, the output starts with a singleton
        // followed by matched pairs, and ending with a singleton
        value = i;
        *data++ = value++;
        for (int j = 0; j < 31; j++)
        {
            *data++ = value;
            *data++ = value++;
        }
        *data++ = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it on an x64 compiling with clang, and the result looked pretty clean. Not sure how well it translates to ARM.

Comment: @user3386109 What I like about your proposal is that it is a bit easier to understand the pattern generation in your code than it is with mine. It could be fun if OP actually did some real measurements and gave us some feedback.

Comment: Agreed, it would be nice to know if these optimizations actually beat what the compiler would do on its own :)